# Grpc load balance with traefik is not working

Tags: load-balancing, grpc, traefik

I hope to use traefik as grpc load balance. Here is the traefik.toml file configuration.

```
logLevel = "INFO"
[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
   address = ":2525"

[file]
   [backends]
      [backends.backend1]
         [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
            url = "http://localhost:6565"
            weight = 10

   [frontends]
      [frontends.frontend1]
      backend = "backend1"
         [frontends.frontend1.headers]
            # SSLRedirect = true
         [frontends.frontend1.routes.Route1]
            rule = "Host:localhost"
```

My grpc server host is `localhost` and port is `6565`. Grpc client sends grpc request to `localhost:6565` (server) will work fine. But when I config traefik to listen port `2525` and ran `traefik`. Changing the grpc client port to `2525` is not load balancing as I request.

But grpc (http2) request are detected by traefik according to access log.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jun/2018:05:23:16 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 404 19 "-" "-" 1 "backend not found" "*" 0ms
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jun/2018:05:23:16 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 404 19 "-" "-" 2 "backend not found" "*" 0ms
```

It says `backend not found`. Its bit hard to understand why this happen. I went through internet for better solution. Some people say to use `https` with this. But when `NGINX` use we no need to use `https`. So I need a solution like that. Can someone give me a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3519) and this [doc](https://docs.traefik.io/master/user-guide/grpc/).

First, we need to change the backend protocol from `http` to `h2c`, which is  http2 without s.

Second, traefik will not support `h2c` backend until `v1.7`, so current release won't work. As the official repo says, they release every other month, and the current version is `v1.6.4`, so we can have this feature next month.

However, if you want to have this right now(like me), we can build a dev version of traefik from source. See this [doc](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md), basicaly just clone the repo and build.